# Can't Send email through Android emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, email, camera

I wrote an email app and I am running it on android emulator. Basically this app captures the picture using camera and then sends it to a person through email. But the problem is when I try to send an email or capture an image from the emualtor, I get error FORCE CLOSE. How can I solve this problem? I don't have an android phone to test the app on the phone.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Share you Log for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Does the test environment have connection to your SMTP server? Sometimes a firewall will prevent an application such as the emulator to reach a secure source such as the SMTP server.

Comment: Try installing a telnet client on the emulator and try connecting to your desired ports.
If you use a commandline client it is usually used the following way:
    telnet <host> <port>

Answer (score 0):

Configure email client in your emulator. Then try for sending email. Also add necessary permissions such as "uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET""
in your AndroidManifest.xml.